# Mean of a numpy array returns Nan

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matplotlib, math

I have a `np.array` and I want to calculate the Mean of that. When I run my code this part of code returns Nan:

```py
data -= np.mean(data, dtype=np.float64)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I'd guess either there are nans in the array or the array is empty.

Comment: @dmuir:I checked the array, some of its values ​​are nan. What should I do?

Comment: Could you add some sample data?

Comment: `np.nan_to_num(x)` can be used to replace NaN values.

Comment: @mpSchrader I added this code and changed the values ​​to 0 instead of nan.But this time after executing the  code( data -= np.mean(data)), np.mean returns infinite.what's the problem?

Comment: Can you add more context around your data? E.g. a toy examples to reproduce your issues.

Answer (score 1):

Because any operation between a number and a NaN returns an NaN, the `np.mean` operation will return NaN if the `data` array contains at least one NaN. You can calculate the mean with the `np.nanmean` function (check the [NumPy's documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html)):

```
data -= np.nanmean(data, dtype=np.float64)
```

**Edit: for arrays containing both NaN and Inf values**

If your array also contains Inf values, you need to calculate the mean without considering both values.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([np.nan, np.inf, 1])
>>> np.mean(x)
nan
>>> np.nanmean(x)
inf
>>> np.nanmean(x[x ~= np.isinf(x)])
1.0
```

Alternatively, you can turn your array into values with `np.nan_to_num`, where you can decide which values can replace NaN, +Inf and -Inf values [as specified in the doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html), so every regular function can work afterwards. For instance in your case, if you want to discard both Inf and NaNs in the mean, you can turn every "bad" value into a NaN, and apply `np.nanmean` on the resulting array:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([np.nan, np.inf, 1])
>>> y = np.nan_to_num(x, nan=np.nan, posinf=np.nan)
>>> y
array([nan, nan,  1.])
>>> y_mean = np.nanmean(y)
>>> y_mean
1.0
```

Comment: I did this but it returned an infinite . Where is the problem?

Comment: Your array may also contain infinite values. In this case, you surely want disregard them. I edited my answer.

Comment: I checked My data and it does not have an infinite value, but after executing the code, it returns infinite.what can I do

Comment: Well, can you share your data (or a subset of your data)? What do `np.min` and `np.max` return? What do you see when you plot it?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have `NaNs` in your array.

You can select all other elements that are not `NaN` like:

```
my_array = my_array[~np.isnan(my_array)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas. It is not as elegant as the np.nanmean() method, but it does allow you to bulldoze your way through and gives you control of axes to average.

```
import pandas as pd
y_mean = pd.DataFrame(y).mean()
```